# Is there any function like 'try' in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, seasoned-schemer

Now I'm leaning schemer by looking the book **The Seasoned Schemer**.
I writed the code by racket, however when I using the `try`, the schemer didn't have this method or macro. And It reported expand: unbound identifier in module in: try.
The code as the below: (in the page 89)

```
(define (remove-member-first* a lat)
   (try oh (rm a lat oh) lat))
```

I've search the racket documents, but didn't find smiliar function.

So who does know whether there are kinda function like the 'try'?

Comment: cf. [this later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29942890/849891).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't mention it, but I'm guessing that the book you're talking about is "The Seasoned Schemer". Use the following macro definitions for implementing `try` as defined in the book:

```
(require mzlib/defmacro)

(define-macro (letcc c . body)
  `(call/cc (lambda (,c) ,@body)))

(define-macro (try x a b)
  `(letcc *success*
     (letcc ,x
       (*success* ,a))
     ,b))
```

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thanks. And I need to add '(require mzlib/defmacro)'.

Comment: I added that to my answer as clarification

Comment: Unhygienic macros are a bad idea, *always*, especially for such a simple macro where you could use just `define-syntax-rule`.

Answer (score 14):

I've just found someone who has already written all code snippets from the book **The Seasoned Schemer** in github.

And it is his answer: ( It is not non-hygienic and don't require other model)

```
(define-syntax letcc
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((letcc var body ...)
     (call-with-current-continuation
       (lambda (var)  body ... )))))


(define-syntax try 
  (syntax-rules () 
    ((try var a . b) 
     (letcc success 
       (letcc var (success a)) . b))))
```

The link is https://github.com/viswanathgs/The-Seasoned-Schemer

Comment: Yay hygiene! Definitely the answer I prefer.

Comment: Note, there is already a letcc in racket, but it is called `let/cc`, further, you should be able to get away with using `let/ec` instead, also using `define-syntax-rule`, you could define try as: `(define-syntax-rule (try var a b ...) (let/ec success (let/ec var (success a)) b ...))`